# how to wrap a backslash as an array item with single or double quote in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like below:
`'°', '=', '{', '}', '\', '%', '©', '®', '™', '✓',`
need to figure out how to wrapper the backslash() in the array. currently it's regarded as error.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is an escape token, so you can just escape it to be treated as a literal. `'\\'`

Answer (score -1):

you could use the `encodeURI("\")` function or escape it directly with `'\\'`

Comment: Test your answer before posting it